# Is it possible to read a csv file that is located in the python project?

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

I have a python project with a handful of python scripts, a domain and repository folder with additional python scripts in each etc.... I'd like to create a config folder within this python project that will contain a csv file for configurations that my python project will use.

I then would like to read this csv file into a dataframe within my python code. Is this possible?
Any search I've done only details reading csv files from an actual file share location like from a C drive or desktop location.

```
df_config = pd.read_csv('Python Config Folder/File_Config.csv', delimiter = ",")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the current directory for this.
Example:

```py
import pathlib
actual_dir = pathlib.Path().absolute()
df_config = pd.read_csv(f'{actual_dir}/File_Config.csv', delimiter = ",")
```

If you want get the previus directory you can use ".."
Exemple:

```py
f'{actual_dir}/../File_Config.csv'
```